# Updating the JTable item with time intervals

Tags: java, swing, jtable

The program that I try to design gets a website URL from user, get its source code and adds the item into the JTable according to the desired data in that source code. However, now it does it only once, when the user clicks the add button. I want it to be dynamically controlled and updated in the JTable with time intervals like 1-2s. Should I use threads for each row (each different element) or are there any other suggestions?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

No.

If you use a thread for each row, you will be overloaded... You should use only a single thread which do all of them one by one... If there is a really big number of row, you may put 2 threads which half each, or 3 with a third each... but not one for each :)

Hope i helped :)

Comment: Or at least use some kind of constrained `ExecutorService` to control the number of threads and allow tasks to be queued